# SmtpClient.Send gets stuck

Tags: c#, smtp

```
string host = "gauntlet.asoshared.com", username= "a@a.test", pwd = "abc",
    from = "a@a.test", to = "b@b.test";
int port = 465;

var mm = new MailMessage(from, to);
mm.Body = "b1";
mm.Subject = "s1";
mm.IsBodyHtml=false;
using (var smtp=new SmtpClient(host, port)) {
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential (username, pwd);
    smtp.Send(mm);
}
```

This stays stuck on `smtp.Send`. After about 2 minutes, I get a timeout error. With Outlook it works perfectly (using my real credentials).
Looking at Wireshark, I see a TCP SYN,SYN-ACK,ACK, and then nothing, when running this code. When using Outlook these are followed by a `TLSv1.2 Client Hello` etc.

Tried adding the following lines at the beginning of the code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue=false;
```

Why is C# getting stuck, and not even sending the `Client Hello`?

It works fine when I use a different host.

**EDIT:** You can reproduce the issue yourself by running the code above **as is**. You will get a timeout error instead of a bad credentials error, and using wireshark, you can see that C# doesn't even attempt the TLS connection.

Comment: There is no problem with your code. Worked fine for me after I put in my host/credentials info. You might want to check logs on the smtp server if you have access to it.

Comment: @just-my-name Did you try my code **as is**, using the host & credentials I posted? Why does it get stuck instead of giving a bad credentials error? If you look at wireshark you will see that C# isn't even attempting to start the TLS connection.

Comment: Yes I did and it behaved as you described. Then I replaced it with my host and it worked just fine. That's why I suspect it has something to do with your smtp server.

Comment: @just-my-name It's not my SMTP server, it's [A Small Orange](https://asmallorange.com/)'s. Besides you haven't explained why Outlook sends just fine, and C# chokes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is implicit SSL.

`System.Net.Mail` only support "explicit" SSL, as explained here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/webdav_101/archive/2008/06/02/system-net-mail-with-ssl-to-authenticate-against-port-465.aspx

Ordinarily this is governed by convention. SMTP running on port 25 (the normal case) uses explicit SSL. SMTPS running on port 465 uses implicit SSL. Mail submission running on port 587 uses explicit SSL.

You could try port `25` if that allows explicit SSL.

Comment: One of the comments there points to this package (if using port 25 isn't an option): https://www.nuget.org/packages/AIM

Answer (score 1):

it's maybe off topic, but I would like to suggest you to use

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

instead of create the smtp client yourself, here's a reason from https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/04/MailKit-MimeKit-Official.

> The main problem with SmtpClient is that it has a confusing connection lifecycle. Connecting to a SMTP server can be time consuming, especially if authentication is enabled, so each SmtpClient object has an internal connection pool.

Comment: After spending few days of debugging the code, tweaking windows,and router's settings , calling my ISP I run across your comment. MailKit worked magically without any issues...

Answer (score -2):

Try the following code.

```
private async Task<bool> SendEmail(string Email, string Message)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("www.test.com");
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@test.com", "password");
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("test@from.com");
            mailMessage.To.Add(Email);
            mailMessage.Body = Message;
            mailMessage.Subject = "abc";
            await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -3):

This piece of code works for me

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient('smtp.domain.com',25);
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential('username', 'password');
    client.EnableSsl = false;
    client.Send(mm);
```

You can try adding **client.DeliveryMethod**

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help.